# Are there any decent .NET MVC frameworks for building rich AJAX applications?

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, rich-internet-application

I'd like to build an application(s) with rich ajax-based user interface. Key UI features would be:

- Realtime data saving (incomplete data that user typed in forms should
  be saved server side)
- Realtime validation (fields should be validated, sometimes validated using server side 
  check, when lost focus)
- Handling URL navigation (with URL # fragment) and browser back
  button
- No page reloading

So in general I'd like the kind of UI like in google applications, wunderkit, asana.
My application will have a lot of forms, lot of input fields and will have to deal with lot of data including file uploads. The previous version of the application use ASP.NET-MVC3 and  ajax is used only in form of few dedicated modules.
The requirement is to build it in .NET and I can't image using anything else than ASP.NET-MVC.

The question is: Is there any decent framework for building such appliactions with .NET MVC 4 or should I rather start building it myself?

UPDATE:
I know there's lot of jQuery plugins for each of ajax UI features. I'm looking for some kind of base for rich ajax applications where these plugins are already chosen. Although I'm starting to realize that maybe creating this base by myself is a better idea.

Comment: I think you're talking about ASP.NET MVC... that stuff is supported but you'll have to write "some" code. What are you trying to do that you can't?

Comment: @hunter: I can do everything I need using current ASP.NET MVC, but I don't want to invent the wheel again.

Comment: What wheel would that be? Saving a form via ajax? You could globally attach any submit events to be posted ajax.

Comment: @hunter: wheel examples: url # fragment navigation, realtime validation. I know there are several iQuery plugins for each of these tasks, but I wonder if there is some kind of thoughtful compilation of such plugins creating a base for big ajax applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's not "invent the wheel again" out there exist so many javascripts libraries to help you. the level of abstraction you're looking for,  you don't find something, at least good.

I always do custom libraries who adapts to the design and keeps the pattern who wants the client to re-use (DRY), remember that not everybody wants the same user interface flow

Answer (score 0):

Just about everything you're asking about can be found in a jQuery plugin.